# Electron NodeJS : MaxListenersExceededWarning:

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I tried to create a desktop application to download about ~150 small files from my S3 bucket through CloudFront. I'm using the electron-dl package to allow my Electron app to download all the files.

However, I encounter this error when it tries to put the download event into a for loop that goes through every single

```
(node:2592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 will-download listeners added to [Session]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:2592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 updated listeners added to [DownloadItem]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:2592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 done listeners added to [DownloadItem]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:2592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 updated listeners added to [DownloadItem]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:2592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 done listeners added to [DownloadItem]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
[15084:0722/105540.244:ERROR:CONSOLE(7)] "Protocol Error: Attempted to dispatch an unspecified method 'Page.downloadProgress': {"method":"Page.downloadProgress","params":{"guid":"9937240f-642f-4be0-b952-546931b0866e","totalBytes":5077952,"receivedBytes":4848853,"state":"inProgress"}}", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/protocol_client/protocol_client.js (7)
[15084:0722/105540.312:ERROR:CONSOLE(7)] "Protocol Error: Attempted to dispatch an unspecified method 'Page.downloadProgress': {"method":"Page.downloadProgress","params":{"guid":"893407ee-d78e-4e03-8101-4f1f72487a2e","totalBytes":5077952,"receivedBytes":3538944,"state":"inProgress"}}", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/protocol_client/protocol_client.js (7)
[15084:0722/105540.367:ERROR:CONSOLE(7)] "Protocol Error: Attempted to dispatch an unspecified method 'Page.downloadProgress': {"method":"Page.downloadProgress","params":{"guid":"a0d07b79-8d6f-4236-9f54-79ae5d4c7b6d","totalBytes":5077952,"receivedBytes":785621,"state":"inProgress"}}", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/protocol_client/protocol_client.js (7)
[15084:0722/105540.378:ERROR:CONSOLE(7)] "Protocol Error: Attempted to dispatch an unspecified method 'Page.downloadProgress': {"method":"Page.downloadProgress","params":{"guid":"1666938f-b4f1-4f20-b13f-521a9e532a72","totalBytes":5077952,"receivedBytes":2883584,"state":"inProgress"}}", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/protocol_client/protocol_client.js (7)
[15084:0722/105540.384:ERROR:CONSOLE(7)] "Protocol Error: Attempted to dispatch an unspecified method 'Page.downloadProgress': {"method":"Page.downloadProgress","params":{"guid":"4b15da26-4ab9-4815-bade-21020d6a2823","totalBytes":5077952,"receivedBytes":2490368,"state":"inProgress"}}", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/protocol_client/protocol_client.js (7)
```

This is my code in the index.js

```
const { remote } = require("electron");
const dialog = remote.dialog;
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

async function Download() {
  var path;

  //Version Input
  var version = document.getElementById("versionValue").value;
  console.log(version);

  //Path Input
  dialog
    .showOpenDialog({
      title: "Select Save Folder",
      properties: ["openFile", "openDirectory"],
    })
    .then((result) => {
      path = result.filePaths.toString();
      path = path.replace(/\\/g, "/") + "/" + version;
      console.log(path); // Get Location Path

      //Dowloand files line by line
      var fs = require("fs"),
        byline = require("byline");
      var stream = byline(
        fs.createReadStream(version+".txt", { encoding: "utf8" })
      );
      stream.on("data", function (line) {
        var tmpUrl = 'http://d2hli22jy1f74m.cloudfront.net/application-version/' + version + "/" + line;
        //Download Handler
        ipcRenderer.send("download", {
          url:
            tmpUrl,
          properties: { directory: path },
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This is my code in the main.js

```
const { dialog, app, BrowserWindow, Menu, session, ipcMain  } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const {download} = require('electron-dl');
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;

let win,login;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 550,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true, // is default value after Electron v5
      enableRemoteModule:true
    },
  });

  login = new BrowserWindow({
    width:450,
    height:550,
    closable:false,
    show:false,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  login.loadURL('http://d2hli22jy1f74m.cloudfront.net/index.html');


  win.webContents.session.clearStorageData();
  login.webContents.session.clearStorageData();

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });

  login.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    login = null;
  });

  //Create Menu toold bar
  var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: "Menu",
      submenu: [
        {
          label: "Login",
          click(){
            login.show();
          }
        },
        {type:'separator'},  
        {
          label: "Exit",
          click() {
            app.quit();
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  var menu2 = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: "Menu",
      submenu: [
        {
          label: "Close",
          click(){
            login.hide();
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  //Declare Different menu
  login.setMenu(menu2)
  win.setMenu(menu)

  //Downloader
  ipcMain.on("download", (event, info) => {
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), info.url, info.properties)
        .then(dl => window.webContents.send("download complete", dl.getSavePath()));
});


}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 voiceStateUpdate listeners added to Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660061/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-voic)