# MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 voiceStateUpdate listeners added to [Client]

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, discord.js

I have this code right here which detects if the bot gets kicked out of voice chat.

```js
const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
const botvc = message.guild.me.voice.channel;
if (botvc === null) {
 if (serverQueue === undefined) {
  const queueConstruct = {
   connection: null,
   songs: [],
   volume: 2,
   playing: true,
  };
  message.client.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
  const newqueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
  if (newqueue.songs[0] !== undefined) {
   newqueue.songs[0].looped = 0;
   message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
  } else {
   message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
  }
 } else {
  serverQueue.songs[0].looped = 0;
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
 }
}
```

It's a `voicestateupdate` event in discord.js which is in an event handler.

Is there anything wrong with the code or anything to fix the memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have other `voiceStateUpdate` listeners in your code or your code is adding the listener (calling `client.on('voiceStateUpdate', listener)`) more than once. The warning (which occurs for all [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)s, not just Discord.js' `Client`) is telling you that adding too many listeners for an event (the default is 10) is possibly a mistake.

Try adding a breakpoint on `client.on('voiceStateUpdate', ...`) when debugging to find out when the listener is added. Alternatively, try using the [`--trace-warnings`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_warnings) flag to see the stack trace for the memory leak warning.

If you do need more than 10 `voiceStateUpdate` listeners (which is unlikely), use [`setMaxListeners`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) to change the maximum number of listeners for an event:

```js
// Changes the maximum number of listeners for an event to 11
client.setMaxListeners(11)
```